# Use form information in external POST request

Tags: django, jira

I've built a simple form to open up a JIRA ticket based on user input.  I've almost got all of it, except I don't know how to use the form element in the POST request.  Here's what I have so far:

```
  <form target="_blank" action='http://baseurl.com/secure/CreateIssueDetails!init.jspa?pid=10517&amp;issuetype=3&amp;summary=Change+application+name+to+{{new_name}}&amp;reporter={{request.user}}&amp;priority=5&amp;assignee=xxx' method='post'>
    <label for="new_name">New name: </label>
    <input id="new_name" type="text" name="new_name" value="{{item.name}}">
    <input type="submit" value="Create JIRA ticket">

  </form>
```

So I just need the value the user puts in the `new_name` element to be passed into the appropriate spot in the URL.  How do I access that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're getting POST and GET mixed. POST data would not be included in the URL itself, but rather in the request payload itself.

So, your URL would be http://baseurl.com/secure/CreateIssueDetails!init.jspa

The payload would be separately put in the body of the HTTP request.

If you need to use a GET method, the URL itself would be the same as above, but the URL that eventually gets hit would be http://baseurl.com/secure/CreateIssueDetails!init.jspa?new_name=WHATEVERVALUE.

If you need additional key-value pairs to get passed, just add them as hidden fields and pass them that way.

Your code, edited:

```
<form target="_blank" action='http://baseurl.com/secure/CreateIssueDetails!init.jspa' method='post'> <!-- ARE YOU SURE IT'S A POST REQUEST AND NOT A GET? -->
    <label for="new_name">New name: </label>
    <input id="new_name" type="text" name="new_name" value="{{item.name}}">
    <input type="hidden" value="10517" name="pid">
    <input type="hidden" value="3" name="issuetype">
    <input type="hidden" value="5" name="priority">
    <input type="hidden" value="Change application name to {{new_name}}" name="summary">
    <input type="hidden" value="{{request.user}}" name="reporter">
    <input type="hidden" value="xxx" name="assignee">
    <input type="submit" value="Create JIRA ticket">

  </form>
```

Makes sense?

Comment: I am decidedly _not_ sure it's a POST instead of a GET.  I've changed it to a GET--which makes more sense-- but still, the summary is being passed through without the new_name variable filled in.

Comment: Gotcha. Based on what the information looks like, it has all the indications of being a POST -- like the name says, you're posting stuff to the server, instead of getting -- but then again, just check the API documentation to make sure you're using the right method. Most often, you can't interchange them unless the server-side allows it. Hope that helps!

Comment: Both GET and POST work, but I can't get the value of new_name to plug in to the value of summary.

Comment: The value of summary should be "Change application name to {{item.name}}.

Comment: So, {{item.name}} is just the default value.  The user should change it to something new.